# TabBar icon color when tab is selected

Tags: flutter, colors, tabs

I'm trying to change color of the tab icon when tab is selected. I know how to change the color of the icon, but I don't know how to make the color change when I select tab.

My code:

```
child: AppBar(
    bottom: TabBar(
        tabs: <Tab>[
            Tab(
                child: new Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                        new Text("Select", textAlign: TextAlign.start),
                        new SizedBox(
                            width: 24.0,
                        ),
                        new Icon(
                            Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                            color: Colors.blue.shade400,
                        ),
                    ],
                    ....
                )
            )
        ]
    )
)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To change the selected tab color, you just need to add this to TabBar :

```
labelColor: Colors.
unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white,
```

Full code:

```
DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          bottom: TabBar(
            labelColor: Colors.deepOrange,
            unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white,
            tabs: <Tab>[
              Tab(
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text("Select", textAlign: TextAlign.start),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 24.0,
                    ),
                    Icon(
                      Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                      color: Colors.blue.shade400,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Tab(
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text("Select", textAlign: TextAlign.start),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 24.0,
                    ),
                    Icon(
                      Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                      color: Colors.blue.shade400,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            child: Text("This is a page blahblah"),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
```

**EDIT:**
If u want to only change the icon color, then add color to Text and remove the color from the Icon in Tab, Code:

```
DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          bottom: TabBar(
            labelColor: Colors.deepOrange,
            unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white,
            tabs: <Tab>[
              Tab(
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text("Select", textAlign: TextAlign.start, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 24.0,
                    ),
                    Icon(
                      Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Tab(
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text("Select", textAlign: TextAlign.start, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 24.0,
                    ),
                    Icon(
                      Icons.arrow_drop_down,

                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            child: Text("This is a page blahblah"),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
```

**EDIT #2**
Now , This code changes the Icon color, but leaves the text color change as default (You can customize the change for color of text like the icon color). Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FirstPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FirstPageState createState() => _FirstPageState();
}

class _FirstPageState extends State<FirstPage> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          bottom: TabBar(
            onTap: (index){
              setState(() {
               _currentIndex = index; 
              });
            },

            tabs: <Tab>[
              Tab(
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text("Select", textAlign: TextAlign.start,),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 24.0,
                    ),
                    Icon(
                      Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                      color: _currentIndex == 0 ? Colors.deepOrange : Colors.white54
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Tab(
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text("Select", textAlign: TextAlign.start,),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 24.0,
                    ),
                    Icon(
                      Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                      color: _currentIndex == 1 ? Colors.deepOrange : Colors.white54,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            child: Text("This is a page blahblah"),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! LabelColor change full label(text and icon) I need, to change color only for Icon.

Comment: @Smith I will edit my answer for only icon color change.

Comment: Okay, now when I unselect tab, textcolor stays white, like this tab is active instead gray like inactive.

Comment: Well then u need both icon and text to change colors. You need statefullwidget for this with _currentIndex as int. I'll edit the code :) .

Answer (score 4):

`TabBar` has the properties `labelColor` and `unselectedLabelColor` to set a selected/unselected color to any icon and text in the `Tabs`.

If you want to have a fixed color for icons or texts in the `Tabs`, you just have to specify that color in the `Icon` or `Text` in the `Tab` to override the color defined in the properties `labelColor` and `unselectedLabelColor` of the `TabBar`.

So, in your case, if you want to have a selected/unselected color for icons and a fixed color for the text, you have to set the `labelColor` and `unselectedLabelColor` in the `TabBar` with the colors for the icons and set a specific color on the text inside the `Tabs`.